# Azure pipeline: get output variable from nested dependency

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I run Azure pipeline to deploy functions.
There is step which deploys functions from ARM template (`DeployFunctionsFromARM` job). This job generates functions key, and puts this key as output variable.

Job1 is dependent on the above mentioned deploy job. So I could take value of the output variable like this `$[dependencies.DeployFunctionsFromARM.outputs['DeployFunctionsFromARM.DeployFunctionsFromARMOutputs.MyFunctionKey']]`

Then I have Job2, which depends on Job1 - and I need also to use function key for this job. Is there a way to access its value similar as for Job1?

```
- job: Job1
    displayName: Dummy Job1
    dependsOn: DeployFunctionsFromARM
    variables:
      FunctionKey: $[dependencies.DeployFunctionsFromARM.outputs['DeployFunctionsFromARM.DeployFunctionsFromARMOutputs.MyFunctionKey']]
- job: Job2
    displayName: Register Callbacks
    dependsOn: Job1
    variables:
      FunctionKey: ???
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation this should be possible:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#use-outputs-in-a-different-job

However the var is set in this example through bash and with [isOutput=true](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-a-multi-job-output-variable).

I tested it with most of your YAML:

```yaml
stages:
- stage: One
  jobs:
  - job: Job1
    displayName: Dummy Job1
    variables:
      FunctionKey: 'hello'
    steps:
    - bash: |
       echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=transfer;isOutput=true]${{ variables.FunctionKey }}"
      name: fk
- stage: Two
  jobs:
  - job: Job2
    displayName: Register Callbacks
    variables:
      # map the output variable from A into this job
      varFromA: $[ stageDependencies.One.Job1.outputs['fk.transfer'] ]
    steps:
    - script: echo $(varFromA) # this step uses the mapped-in variable
```

[image: test results]

Comment: @promico, thanks a lot!  Just a small update - it works if `FunctionKey` variable is set as value directly, in `Job1`. If it is set as expression (as in my case, from output variable), then during setting of output variable `transfer`, value of `FunctionKey` should be used using macros syntax, like this" `echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=transfer;isOutput=true]$(FunctionKey)"`.